# make ifndef inverse behavior

Tags: c++, makefile

```
ifndef CC
  CC := icc
endif

override CC := $(CC)
```

Then the result of

```
make
```

is that `CC=cc`. `make CC=gcc` is right.

If I change `ifndef` to `ifdef` then `CC=icc` and everything works ok.

How does it work?

Comment: What does this have to do with C++, really?

Comment: It would be more about meta-programming, would it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CC` is defined by default. So `make` is equivalent to `make CC=cc`.

You could skip the conditional entirely and get the behavior you seem to want:

```
override CC := icc
```